# How to determine all blocks and child blocks attached to a handle?

Tags: layout, blocks

Is there a way to determine which blocks are attached to a handle and/or what child-blocks a block have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get all handles
see **Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update::getHandles()**

For example inside a controller you can use it for debugging purposes like:

```
Zend_Debug::dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
```

Note: use it after loadLayout or loadLayoutUpdates call

To get all block children see
**Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::getChild()** without parameters
Note: the getChild() returns all child blocks as an object so used something like

```
Zend_Debug::dump(array_keys($block->getChild()))
```

and you get an array with child block alias names

and if you want to see more about a block use

```
Zend_Debug::dump($block->getChild($aliasName))
```

Comment: And use `$this->getLayout()->getUpdate->addHandle('handle')` or `...addHandle(array('handle','other_handle'))` to load a specific handle for dumping.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following free extension which is very handy in debugging:[http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-debug-8676.html](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magneto-debug-8676.html)

Comment: Very handy indeed!

Answer (score 0):

I think I might figured out the answer and it is pretty simple. Just search by handle or block name from all files in layout folder :)

Comment: Would be nice if someone could confirm this being conclusive.

Comment: Searching in the layout files for a layout handle or reference tags for a block in question is likely to return all the blocks you are interested in, but it's worth noting that it won't take into account those blocks created 'on the fly' through a call to the `createBlock()` method on the layout object.

Comment: I knew there was something more :) Tnx! You should make it an answer.