# how to print a list of available blocks from a template?

Tags: blocks

I am trying to find an existing block to call it from my template

is it possible to use something like:

```
    <?php var_dump( $this->getLayout()->getAllBlocks() );?>
```

this gives me a 505 error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the blocks in the layout are huge objects that have references to other huge objects and at one point you get a circular reference an `var_dump` crashes.
If you want to get the names of the available blocks do this:

```
var_dump(array_keys($this->getLayout()->getAllBlocks()));
```

then if you find the key you need you can just print it out like this:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('KEY HERE')->toHtml();
```

You can even call the line above without knowing if the block exists but call it a little different:

```
if ($block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('KEY HERE')) {
    echo $block->toHtml();
}
```

Comment: this is awesome ! u have made my day !!

Answer (score 2):

I hope this might help you, if you want to enlist all static blocks:

```
 Mage::getResourceModel('cms/block_collection')->load()->toOptionArray();
```

Comment: interesting but id does not list blocks declared in layout , right?

Comment: It will give you list of all blocks, you can rectify the result as per you need

Comment: it gives only cms blocks

Comment: You can use this link:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3090/how-to-determine-all-blocks-and-child-blocks-attached-to-a-handle