# how to use the addBlock method in templates?

Tags: blocks

having block declaration from layout , say:

```
    <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
```

how can i use addblock in a template for displaying the block

```
       /* @var $this Mage_Core_Block_Template */
     echo $this->getLayout()->addBlock($block, $blockName)->toHtml() ;
```

Comment: Do you mean calling a static block from template file?

Comment: @TBI Infotech no , i mean a block declared in a layout xml file elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found out from [how to print a list of available blocks from a template?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22162/how-to-print-a-list-of-available-blocks-from-a-template/22168#22168)

that this was working nicely

```
echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.search')->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 1):

we use create block

For example:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml')->toHtml()
```